# Add a label to a DRAFT

Tags: gmail-api

Simple question, given a Draft instance, how can I add a label to it?

Attempting to simply add labels to the LabelIds property of a draft before updating creates this error:

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Cannot set labels on drafts [400]
Errors [    
   Message[Cannot set labels on drafts]
   Location[ - ] Reason[invalidArgument] Domain[global]
]
```

In the gmail UI, it's possible to drag a label onto a draft and even using the API, I can search drafts by label, but can draft labels be **SET** via the API?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels#applying_labels_to_messages_and_threads), "Messages and threads can have multiple labels associated with them; **however, draft messages cannot have labels applied to them**."

Comment: This is unfortunate since you can easily add labels to draft messages listed in the normal web interface.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by modifying the message after it has been created

```
Draft draft = new Draft();
draft.setMessage( ... );
draft = service.users().drafts().create(userId, draft).execute();

List<String>labs = new ArrayList<>();
labs.add("<label_ID>");
ModifyMessageRequest mmr = new ModifyMessageRequest().setAddLabelIds(labs); 
service.users().messages().modify(userId, draft.getMessage().getId(), mmr).execute();
```

Comment: Worked for me, using PHP.